# Running an API from server with a masked url

Tags: python, flask

I have created an API which i have made accessible publicly using host='0.0.0.0'. However, i do not want to expose the I.P address to the users. How do i give a name to the url so that users can hit the name instead of I.P.? Below is the code suite

```
from flask import Flask

from dev import myfunc

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    myfunc()
    return "Script Completed"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

Comment: you need access the IP address of the machine where you've setup. first know the public ip address of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

from the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/):

> Externally Visible Server
>
> If you run the server you will notice that the server is only
>   accessible from your own computer, not from any other in the network.
>   This is the default because in debugging mode a user of the
>   application can execute arbitrary Python code on your computer.
>
> If you have the debugger disabled or trust the users on your network,
>   you can make the server publicly available simply by adding
>   --host=0.0.0.0 to the command line:
>
> flask run --host=0.0.0.0
>
> This tells your operating system to listen on all public IPs.